# method to check if number is ascending order by recursion

Tags: java, recursion

method name:

```
public static boolean ascendingNum(int n)
```

method need to be done by recursion and return if the given number is in ascending order from right to left

```
  public static boolean ascendingNum(int n) {
///123456 true
// 987654 true
// 123455 false
if(n > 9 && n < 100)
 if(n / 10 < n % 10)
  return true;
  else if(n / 10 >= n % 10)
     return false;
if(((n / 10) % 10)  ==  (n % 10 ))
return false;

 if ( ((n / 10) % 10)  <  (n % 10 ))
        return(ascendingNum(n/10));
   return false;
}
```

from running the numbers like in the comments it worked fine,can i have your opinion?

Comment: Why are both `123456` and `987654` both "ascending"?  Seems like one should be considered "descending".

Comment: Please format your code. You are wasting our precious free time by forcing us to decrypt this unreadable mess.

Comment: It's a typo. 987654 returns false when the code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The erratic formatting makes this code exceedingly difficult to read. The line indents are all over the place, and the whitespace is inconsistent. The code should have a consistent indent depth, preferably 2 or 4 spaces. There should be whitespace after control flow operators (`if (`) and none in between multiple parentheses. There should be no whitespace before a `)`.

Curly braces are technically optional for single-line blocks, but they should always be used. They greatly increase the readability of the code, which is crucial for preventing errors and for future maintainability.

Use blank lines to break up clauses in the code.

Just making those changes:

```
public static boolean ascendingNum2(int n) {
    if (n > 9 && n < 100) {
        if (n / 10 < n % 10) {
            return true;
        } else if (n / 10 >= n % 10) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    if (((n / 10) % 10) == (n % 10)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (((n / 10) % 10) < (n % 10)) {
        return (ascendingNum(n / 10));
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Now it's possible to review.

The first `if` block is mostly extraneous. Set your base case to be a single-digit number. Right now, single-digit numbers fall through to the second clause, and report `false`. I would expect that any single-digit number is vacuously true.

If you do that, you can replace the whole first clause with a check if the number is less than 10. Your second and third clauses handle two-digit numbers correctly.

Your second and third clauses are doing the same math twice. Extract those values to variables. Give them good names, because readability is quite possibly the single most important property of good code.

Instead of checking `==` (false), then `>` (recurse), and defaulting to false for `<`, check for `<=` and return false, then default to recursing.

The code does not handle negative numbers. I would assume they should be false. If the expected behavior isn't specified, ask.

If the method name isn't set by the question, I think `isAscendingNum(12345)` is easier to read.

If you made all these changes, your code might look more like:

```
public static boolean isAscendingNum(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    
    if (n < 10) {
        return true;
    }

    int lastDigit = n % 10;
    int secondToLastDigit = (n / 10) % 10;
    if (lastDigit <= secondToLastDigit) {
        return false;
    }
    return isAscendingNum(n / 10);
}
```

Comment: thank you for help,sorry for the messy code i`l take your notes